# Expectation of distance of two iid random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm reading up on 'energy distance' to use possibly as an analysis tool for images of different textures. I'm reading the paper "*Energy statistics: A class of statistics based on distances*" by Gábor J. Székely and Maria L. Rizzo.
They mention the Cramér distance, and the extension, Cramér–von Mises Smirnov distance and how they are not rotationally invariant for spaces of dim(F) > 1. This is the basic argument for why the energy distance is introduced.

The univariate Cramér-distance is defined as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (F(x)_n-F(x)) dx$$
The univariate Cramér–von Mises Smirnov as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (F(x)_n-F(x)) dF(x)$$

My questions regard the rotational invariance:

- What does rotationally invariant (in the multivariate case) mean here? If we identically rotate both cdfs. F<sub>n</sub> (the empirical cdf) and F  why would the C-MS distance not be the same? Do they mean only rotating one distribution at the time? And if so, what would this mean in practice? F<sub>n</sub> is supposed to be approaching F asymptotically, right?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how is the cdf of a multivariate distribution defined here? In particular, so that it is univariate (given the integral)?

Comment: The one I've written is the univariate one. The multivariate is as you'd expect. I will edit to reflect it. My bad :). Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: That'd be a good idea, since for the univariate case "rotationally invariant" is not that meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotational invariance of a distance $D$ means that for random variables $X,Y$ and a unitary matrix $U$, that $D(X,Y)=D(UX,UY)$. Note that you are rotating the random variables, not the cdf. The cdfs $F_X$ of $X$ and $F_{UX}$ of $UX$ are not related in any simple way.

For example, suppose that $X$ is a point mass at $(1,2)$. Then $F_X(x)=1$ if $x$ is to the north east of $(1,2)$, and $F_X(x)=0$ otherwise. On the other hand, let $U$ be rotation by $90^\circ$. Then $UX$ is a point mass at $(-2,1)$, and the cdf $F_{UX}$ is one to the north and east of $(-2,1)$. Notice that this is not a rotation of $F_X$.

Comment: So, very non-rigorous; Rotation of the possibly outcomes of a random variable changes the Cramér distance in 'unpredictable' ways (otherwise you could just add some function dependent on the rotation to keep the expression for the Cramer distance rotationally invariant).

A follow-up, in the asymptotic case, (n -> $\infty$): F$_n$ = F, right? So, even if we rotate the random variables, at n = $\infty$ it's rotationally invariant?

Comment: @CupinaCoffee I do not know enough to answer your follow-up.